# Incremental Deployment and Rename Site URL

Tags: publishing-site

We have a staging and production environment setup. Incremental deployment is configured from Stage to Production.

We have one sitecollection /

Inside that we have several subsites. One of the subsite in abc-site. The URL to access same would be /abc-site/pages/default.aspx. Now i need to change the URL to abc-site to new-site. I have seen the option to change the URL . But will this cause a problem in Incremental Deployment

Comment: Why will this cause a problem? Why can't you change the URL after the deployment?

Comment: In incremental deployment ideally you change in stage